# What is the relationship between Thread.sleep and happens-before?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've written a simple application, which has main thread(producer) and multiple consumer threads. I want to broadcast a message from main thread, so all the consumer threads will receive it. 
However, I have troubles.
I'm trying to understand how [Thread.sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) may be related to [Happens-Before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5). Here's my piece of code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class PubSub {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Consumer> consumers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
            Consumer consumer = new Consumer(
                    "Consumer"  + i
            );
            consumer.start();

            consumers.add(consumer);
        }

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true) {
            String message = scanner.nextLine();

            for (Consumer consumer: consumers) {
                consumer.notify(message);
            }

        }
    }

    static class Consumer extends Thread {

        private Queue<String> queue;

        public Consumer(String name) {
            super(name);
            this.queue = new LinkedList<>();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {

                if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                    String message = queue.poll();

                    System.out.println(
                            getName() + ": Consuming message: " + message
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        public void notify(String message) {
            queue.add(message);
        }
    }

}
```

If I add sleep, the consumer will start receiving messages:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(true) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(0);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            String message = queue.poll();

            System.out.println(
                    getName() + ": Consuming message: " + message
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Since Thread.sleep is a native method, I want to understand how it resolves happens-before.

I must note, that the true way of fixing happens-before is to make **volatile** keyword:

```
private volatile Queue<String> queue;
```

If you add **synchronization** onto the **queue**, it will also fix the issue:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (queue) {
        while (true) {

            if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                String message = queue.poll();

                System.out.println(
                        getName() + ": Consuming message: " + message
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you think how they can be related?

Comment: @hhafeez I don't know, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: When it doubt, consult the documentation.  The Javadoc for `thread.sleep()` says nothing about "happens before" or "synchronization."  I would therefore assume that there are no guarantees, and if I _needed_ some form of synchronization, I would turn to some other mechanism to ensure it.

Comment: What OS are you on? I'd guess Linux?

Comment: @JohnVint This is reproducible on Windows and Mac as well for me.

Comment: @JohnVint I am using OS X

Comment: `Thread.sleep` has no reason to help with synchronization, even though it appears to do so. Interestingly, in this perticular case, even `volatile` should NOT help. You are spinlocking on `isEmpty()` which internally checking whether `int size` is zero or not. Making the object reference volatile will not make the `size` volatile and `isEmpty` will NOT be a volatile read. Why either of volatile or thread sleep works, is an answer worth bounty.

Comment: I have been playing around with this code for some time and the addition of statements that are evaluated at runtime (such as `this.toString();` for example) right after the `while` loop in `Consumer` causes the consumer to start consuming messages. Addition of statements such as `char s = "abc".charAt(1);` on the other hand don't help the consumer to consume messages. I am starting to feel `Thread.sleep` has got nothing to do with this behavior.

Comment: @inquisitive I was thinking the same about volatile as you but that's not the true. Volatile does not have anything to do with locking. Volatile is a marker that every time thread access a resource it will be provided from the main memory instead of thread's local copy. So yes volatile DOES help in this case.

Comment: @hhafeez, volatile has not much to do with main memory, at least directly, but that is not the point. Even if it had been the case, marking the object reference volatile would make only the reference uncached. The private variable inside the object is still nonvolatile and hopefully cached.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to understand how Thread.sleep may be related to Happens-Before

There is **no** relationship between *happens-before* and `Thread.sleep`. The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3) clearly specifies that `Thread.sleep` does not have any synchronization symantics :

> Neither a sleep for a period of zero time nor a yield operation need have observable effects.
>   It is important to note that neither **Thread.sleep** nor **Thread.yield** have any synchronization
>   semantics. In particular, the compiler does not have to flush writes cached in registers out to
>   shared memory before a call to sleep or yield, nor does the compiler have to reload values cached
>   in registers after a call to sleep or yield. For example, in the following (broken) code fragment,
>   assume that this.done is a non-volatile boolean field:
>
> `while (!this.done)
>         Thread.sleep(1000);`
>
> The compiler is free to read the field this.done just once, and reuse the cached value in each execution of the loop. This would mean that the loop would never terminate, even if another thread changed the value of this.done

---

On a related note, the consumer seems to start consuming messages (on my machine) if one adds statements that are evaluated at runtime right after the `while` loop. For example, the addition of `this.toString()` causes the consumer to start consuming messages.

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
       this.toString();
```

This still does not explain the behavior but it further confirms that `Thread.sleep` is not necessarily the reason behind the `Consumer` suddenly seeing the updates made to the queue.

Comment: What I think is important is the sentence `In particular, the compiler does not have to flush writes cached in registers out to shared memory before a call to sleep or yield`, specifically it saying "does not have to". You are 100% right that it's not documented to require it, however, it does appear to be some ordering mechanism here, considering it seems to have the same effect as volatile.

Comment: My comment is more related to curiosity - in practice, is there actually some sync barrier?

Comment: @JohnVint I believe that statement probably means that there is no requirement that writes should always be flushed but it can happen under certain circumstances. I don't think it means that implementations are free to create a barrier when `Thread.sleep` is called. This is further confirmed by the preceding statement : *It is important to note that neither Thread.sleep nor Thread.yield have any synchronization semantics*. This feels like an affirmation rather than an option. That said, do you think this being enforced at a much deeper level than the runtime itself?

Comment: It's certainly a fair point, but if there should be absolutely no synchronization semantics, why does include a `Thread.sleep` appear to have similar effects to a `volatile` read?

Comment: @JohnVint I have been playing around with this code for some time and the addition of statements that are evaluated at runtime (such as `this.toString();` for example) right after the `while` loop in `Consumer` causes the consumer to start consuming messages. Addition of statements such as `char s = "abc".charAt(1);` on the other hand don't help the consumer to consume messages. I am starting to feel `Thread.sleep` has got nothing to do with this behavior.

Comment: Ah. I know why it's happening with `this.toString()`. The `toString()` method is calling `getName()` and `Thread#name` is a volatile. In essence, `this.toString()` is forcing a `volatile` load which would explain why you're seeing it.

Comment: @JohnVint But `volatile` creates a memory barrier for a particular variable and not everything that happens around it?

Comment: It **does** create the barrier for everything around it within that thread. What is important here is that the `volatile` tells the CPU to not re-order variables above the volatile read. In this case, what is likely happening, is that the reading of name prevents the CPU for hoisting the `isEmpty()` check.

Comment: This is also why it's true that "All writes that occur prior to a volatile store happens-before a subsequent volatile load, regardless of if the writes prior to the store are volatile."

Comment: Try it with `this.getId()` (`tid` is not volatile) and you will see the same behavior as before

Comment: @JohnVint Yup. Seems to only work with `this.toString()` or `this.getName()` as of now. This is getting more and more interesting. The JLS seems to imply that there is no synchronization semantics for sleep. I am still trying to wrap my head around the `volatile` part though. Where did you get this from *All writes that occur prior to a volatile store happens-before a subsequent volatile load, regardless of if the writes prior to the store are volatile*.

Comment: Off the top of my head :) I have read it a bunch to know that's true but I'll find out real documentation

Comment: If you read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5, `If hb(x, y) and hb(y, z), then hb(x, z).`. So if we have a normal store `x` then volatile store `y` and subsequent volatile load `z` by this definition `x happens before z`. And further down `A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field.`

Comment: @JohnVint I am a bit brain dead because of the contradictions in the JLS vs the behavior so pardon my ignorance. Wouldn't the name of the thread be written **before** a value is inserted in the queue? What you describe would make sense if the name of the thread was written **after** a value was inserted in the queue. In this case, the non volatile write is happening **after** the volatile write whereas what you describe is the non volatile write happening **before** the volatile write?

Comment: Totally a fair point. I read through a bit and it does "violate" standard happens-before ordering. That is, the `NormalLoad` is allowed to be ordered above the `VolatileLoad` so by definition it can still fail. That being said, I quoted violate because there isn't actually a happens-before ordering, so all expectations defined in the JLS can be thrown out. It is clear, however, that there is some ordering fence issued, similar to a `VolatileLoad` when sleeping or yielding.

Answer (score 1):

All indications of the code example above is that there is some kind of fence being issued. For example, if the `queue` is not volatile, the `System.in` will never trigger the `Consumer` once the `Consumer` is volatile, things would happen as they should. When issuing a sleep or yield, the app acts as if the queue were volatile.

#### Before reading the rest of my answer:

CKing's answer is the right one in terms of expectation. That is, no where in the JLS is it documented that there is any type of synchronization barrier when issuing a `Thread.sleep` or `Thread.yield`. One should NOT use `Thread.sleep` or `Thread.yield` as a synchronization point analogous to `volatile` as the underlying implementation can change for any release.

#### My suspicion

My answer from here on out was to satisfy my curiosity as to what is going on, and to do that I went into the native code for linux and Windows. You can find this snippet in `src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp`.

A good chunk has been emitted to what I think is the relevant code

```
int os::sleep(Thread* thread, jlong millis, bool interruptible) {
  assert(thread == Thread::current(),  "thread consistency check");

  ParkEvent * const slp = thread->_SleepEvent ;
  slp->reset() ;
  OrderAccess::fence() ;

  if (interruptible) {
    jlong prevtime = javaTimeNanos();

    for (;;) {
      .... other code ...

      prevtime = newtime;

      {
        assert(thread->is_Java_thread(), "sanity check");
        JavaThread *jt = (JavaThread *) thread;
        ThreadBlockInVM tbivm(jt);
        OSThreadWaitState osts(jt->osthread(), false /* not Object.wait() */);

        jt->set_suspend_equivalent();
        // cleared by handle_special_suspend_equivalent_condition() or
        // java_suspend_self() via check_and_wait_while_suspended()

        slp->park(millis);

        // were we externally suspended while we were waiting?
        jt->check_and_wait_while_suspended();
      }
    }
  ... other code ...
```

It's issuing a fence and eventually suspending the thread. I believe this is the relevant information to tell us what is happening and why we see similar behaviors to `volatile`.

Note: This doesn't happen only because of a `native` call. You can invoke `Thread.currentThread()` which is also native but see behaviors as if it were not volatile.

Answer (score 0):

This particular program has nothing to do with sleep or even synchronization. I just proved that it works without sleep and synchronization too. if you notice there is nothing to synchronize here as there are no shared variables. I think it's just a timing thing in that there is no guarantee what moment a particular thread will execute a particular line of code in its run method. I just put a for loop after while
       `for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){}` 
and without sleep or synchronize it started to print values in que. I am even able to print messages with out introduction of for loop if I debug the code.
**updated method**

```
public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {

            }


            if (!queue.isEmpty())
            {
                String message = queue.poll();

                System.out.println(getName() + ": Consuming message: " + message);
            }
        }
```

**update:**
So after doing some more analysis of the code, it turns out the OP was somehow right asking relationship. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html
Defining volatile, does establish happened-before relationship. which guarantees that other threads can see the update. Note here that we are updating the consumer in main thread and child thread has its own copy of variables and child thread does see the update in consumer if que is volatile 
Now come to second part, JVM does some optimization and reordering (which is upredictable) behind the scene by looking at the nature of code. when we introduce some code or statement like for loop or thread.sleep the compiler decides differently and it might say lets get the updated variable while executing this line and that's why we see the messages coming after introducing some statements after the while loop. I checked updating the consumer in child thread and its work fine (prints messages correcly) without volatile synchronization,sleep or any dummy line of code we injected after while.

Comment: Debugging may introduce memory barriers. I don't think it's timing. It does a busy spin checking the existence of data. And when data is successfully added into the queue, nothing gets printed (ie: the consuming thread never polls it from the queue). Adding `volatile` resolves this. It appears to be a classic compiler ordering issue.

Comment: I agree but how would you explain when it works with introduction of for loop like this

Comment: I tried introducing the `for` loop and couldn't recreate it. Can you post the code in more detail and I will try that?

Comment: it does not work for smaller loops but the value like 1000 has caused some timing delay

Comment: This still does not answer why either thread sleep or volatile appears to be working

Comment: yes it does not but its a counter example that suggest volatile,sleep or synchronize has nothing to do with nature of the problem (even though it appears to be). My conjecture is that sleeping for a 0 second still cause sufficient delay, (like the for loop) and volatile is completely different story. So it appears there is some timing issue

Comment: if you are spinning 1000 times, and the spinning is still happening prior to your user input, the elements would exist in the queue. It is definitely a timing use case, but doesn't explain why we never see a timing issue with volatile or `Thread.sleep`

Comment: @John Vint Now I know for sure its not a timing issue (it appears as though) since the claim can easily be refuted by the argument that if it was a timing issue then at least after the update to main thread we could see the update but even after running for long time the child thread does not get updates from main thread. I reluctantly say that it's polymorphic behavior of JVM which does optimization in it's own way by looking at the code. Some time it decides to optimization and sometime it does not.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it is typical issue with visibility of shared object.
You add to queue from main thread, but read it from another one.
There is nothing here related to **Thread.sleep()**

Comment: Then why does declaring the `queue` volatile allow it to function correctly? Thread.sleep appears to have similar effects.

Comment: Result of  volatile is that  consumer thread will see last version queue.

Comment: My question is why does it successfully log, if Thread.yield() or Thread.sleep(0) is introduced before the read, similar to if the queue is volatile